# Is it possible to create related objects on parent creation automatically in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Profile model and NotificationSettings model with OneToOne relation. There is more than one way to create Profile, but NotificationSettings must be created with all of them. I don't want to write same code for every view that creates Profile. So i was hoping that there is some event that i can track so NotificationSettings would be created automatically. Something similar to RubyOnRails' after_create callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the save method of the models to do what you want like this

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

See more in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/)